# Eight OEM-partitions and three EFI-partitions on disk 0?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

Computer management's snap in for disk management shows that there are eight (8) OEM-partitions and  three (3) EFI-partitions on disk 0, which is a 240GB SanDisk Ultra II SSD housing only Windows 10 Pro. They are all used by mostly 17%, meaning that there is some data stored on them.

Can I remove them or are they essential and I risk bricking my system?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The partitions that hava drive letters, C to H, you may examine to see
if you need the data in them. You should certainly not delete disk C.

I see only two EFI-partitions. 
One of them contains boot code, so is not to be touched.
They are small, so not worth the risk of deleting the wrong one.

The 8 OEM-partitions were created when Windows was updated.
They are used to factory reset the computer to its state when delivered
or when Windows was installed.
Eight is a bit excessive, and may have been created when reinstalling
Windows repeatedly using an OEM-supplied boot CD.
They are also quite small, so no point in deleting them and losing this
option to go back to the original state, just in case disaster strikes.

In short: The tiny percentage of wasted disk space is not worth the risk
of damaging a perfectly working computer. So don't delete them.

Comment: Initial install was made via OEM/System Builder license of Windows 10 Pro 64bit, which I bought separately. There has been no reinstallation, only Windows Update/Upgrade as part of the Windows Insider program.

Comment: Windows Update when installing a major version may create such an OEM partition. Notice that their size is slightly increasing, since successive Windows versions are always larger and require more space. Logically the smaller ones may be deleted - you may delete all of them if you have a good recent reinstallation CD that won't break. But from my point of view the tiny gain is not worth the risk of making an error. And for using the new space, you will need to move partitions and consolidate empty disk space, which is always a risky proposition.

Comment: You are sure that those OEM-partitions were created by Windows, e.g while in-place upgrades (those major upgrades (not updates) if you swich to a new version, e.g. from 1709 to 1803 (latest insider preview) happen? So, should I ask MS directly? You may delete the following in own discretion: sorry for the need to edit my initial question, I hoped to make everything right this time. :(

Comment: Windows is supposed to reuse these partitions when they have enough space, but nothing is sure. Last words : These partitions are small and you don't know (and I don't) which ones are needed. Recovering from deleting the wrong ones requires knowledge.

Comment: I remark again that the 8 partitions are excessive. The most I've seen up to now was 3-4. I don't know the history behind it, but each is about half-gigabyte. In all 4 GB out of what seems like 3 TB = 3000 GB. Really nothing.

Comment: Caution: 2 physical disks, one 240GB SSD on which those 8 OEM-partitions are and one 2TB Seagate Enterprise Capacity HDD. So, it matters if you've got 4GB of 240GB (that's 1,66%). Not a lot, but 4GB you could use better.